# Create array tree of nth level form array list

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I have only Nth number of level array return, this function return all children list

```
$arr = array(
array('id'=>100, 'parentid'=>0, 'name'=>'a'),


array('id'=>101, 'parentid'=>100, 'name'=>'a'),
  array('id'=>102, 'parentid'=>101, 'name'=>'a'),
  array('id'=>103, 'parentid'=>101, 'name'=>'a'),
);

$new = array();
foreach ($arr as $a){
    $new[$a['parentid']][] = $a;
}
$tree = createTree($new, array($arr[0]));
print_r($tree);

function createTree(&$list, $parent){
    $tree = array();
    foreach ($parent as $k=>$l){
        if(isset($list[$l['id']])){
            $l['children'] = createTree($list, $list[$l['id']]);
        }
        $tree[] = $l;
    } 
    return $tree;
}
```

this function return all data in array.

this function return cant return the particular level is complete then break and return values

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: this function return cant return the particular level is complete then break and return values

Comment: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/4212770/51d75c43c8ad9a3878d18ad89395af7e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this.

```
$array = array(
    array('id'=>100, 'parentid'=>0, 'name'=>'a'),
    array('id'=>101, 'parentid'=>100, 'name'=>'a'),
    array('id'=>102, 'parentid'=>101, 'name'=>'a'),
    array('id'=>103, 'parentid'=>101, 'name'=>'a')
);

echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_to_tree($array));
exit;
```

**Function to convert tree.**

```
function array_to_tree(array $array, $parent_id = 0)
{
    $array = array_combine(array_column($array, 'id'), array_values($array));

    foreach ($array as $k => &$v) {
        if (isset($array[$v['parentid']])) {
            $array[$v['parentid']]['children'][$k] = &$v;
        }
        unset($v);
    }

    return array_filter($array, function($v) use ($parent_id) {
        return $v['parentid'] == $parent_id;
    });
}
```

Output will be.

[image]

As per your requirement you want only 2 levels then don't use recursive function.
//remove **createTree** from foreach

```
function createTree(&$list, $parent){
    $tree = array();
    foreach ($parent as $k=>$l){
        if(isset($list[$l['id']])){
            $l['children'] = $list[$l['id']]; //remove createTree from here.
        }
        $tree[] = $l;
    } 
    return $tree;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is 3 level shows but i am shown only 2 level 100 and 101 i can't show 102 and 103

Comment: Your array has 3 levels of child right? why you want only 2 levels? If you do this then in every array you'll get only 2 levels.

Comment: Your array has 3 levels of child right? why you want only 2 levels? If you do this then in every array you'll get only 2 levels

yes

Comment: function createTree(&$list, $parent){
    $tree = array();
    foreach ($parent as $k=>$l){
        if(isset($list[$l['id']])){
            $l['children'] = createTree($list, $list[$l['id']]);
        }
        $tree[] = $l;
    } 
    return $tree;
}

return same output

Answer (score 0):

This pre-processes the input data so that the order in which they are processed is in parent ID descending then ID ascending.  This means that you can then just accumulate all of the menus in one pass (some comments in code)...

```
$array = array(
    array('id'=>100, 'parentid'=>0, 'name'=>'a'),
    array('id'=>101, 'parentid'=>100, 'name'=>'a'),
    array('id'=>102, 'parentid'=>101, 'name'=>'a'),
    array('id'=>103, 'parentid'=>101, 'name'=>'a')
);

print_r(array_to_tree($array));

function array_to_tree ( array $input ): array {
    $new = [];
    // Sort data in reverse order of parent ID, normal order of ID within parent ID
    usort($input, function ( $a, $b ) {
        return ( $a['parentid'] == $b['parentid'] )? 
            $a['id']- $b['id']:
            $b['parentid'] - $a['parentid'];
    });
    foreach ( $input as $inp )  {
        // Add data to parent ID
        $new[$inp['parentid']][$inp['id']] = $inp;
        // If data already exists for this ID, then this is also a parent
        if ( isset( $new[$inp['id']]) )   {
            // Add existing data to new item and remove old one
            $new[$inp['parentid']][$inp['id']] += $new[$inp['id']];
            unset($new[$inp['id']]);
        }
    }

    return $new;
}
```