# Laravel categories and Performance

Tags: php, laravel

I used self-referential model to build nested category:

```php
class Category extends Model {

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Category', 'parent_id');
    }

   // recursive, loads all descendants
   public function childrenRecursive()
   {
      return $this->children()->with('childrenRecursive');
   }
}
```

and to get parents with all their children:

```php
$categories = Category::with('childrenRecursive')->whereNull('parent')->get();
```

But i've faced performance issues for my large table (3 level nested category)
Is there any better way to retrieve categories?

And my second question. assume that my categories is something like this:

```
- Digital
 - Mobiles
   - Power Banks
   - Cover & Bumper
 - Computers
- Health
   - Bar
```

And my posts can be in any category like `Digital` or `Mobiles` or `Powerbank`
When user ask me about `Digital` category i should show my users all of my post in this category or in child categories of `Digital`.
And when ask me about `Mobiles` i should show my users all of my post in this category or in child categories of `Mobile`
How can i do it?

Comment: Could you add your post model ?

Comment: get all records by MySQL query and make Recursive function in PHP. check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57783028/9978078. It'll be much faster than model relationship.

Comment: you can read about the nested set model.

Answer (score 3):

```
$categoryWithNestedSubCategoriesAndProducts = Category::with(['products', 'childrenRecursive', 'childrenRecursive.products'])->where('id',$id)->get()->toArray();
```

**Flatten laravel recursive relationship collection**

First, we should Flatten our laravel recursive relationship collection (tree collections) using function like

```
public function flatten($array)
{
        $flatArray = [];

        if (!is_array($array)) {
            $array = (array)$array;
        }

        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
                $flatArray = array_merge($flatArray, $this->flatten($value));
            } else {
                $flatArray[0][$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $flatArray;
}
```

---

**Get list of products**

```
$categoryWithNestedSubCategoriesAndProducts = Category::with(['products', 'childrenRecursive', 'childrenRecursive.products'])->where('id', $id)->get()->toArray();

$flatten = $this->flatten($categoryWithNestedSubCategoriesAndProducts);

foreach ($flatten as $key => $fl) {
    // eliminate categories from $flatten array
    if (!array_key_exists('category_id', $fl)) {
        unset($flatten[$key]);
    }
}

$products = array_values($flatten);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the method I used for my project.
I get a list of all the categories and then control them. I didn't find any suitable way to use eloquent in this case.
I recommend reading the link below.
[hierarchical data](https://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/)

Comment: You may take a look https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite